# Scheduler UILocalNotification is not working when app is on the foreground using ios 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uilocalnotification

`UILocalNotification` is not firing When the app is on the foreground mode , but the same code is Working fine when the app is on the background , getting this info from Logs the user info  is always Null when the app is on the foreground mode .

> fire date = Friday, September 4, 2015 at 6:28:37 PM India Standard
>   Time, time zone = Asia/Kolkata (GMT+5:30) offset 19800, repeat
>   interval = 0, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount,
>   next fire date = (null), user info = (null)

Please check this Sample code i am use this code in my application [example code](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/LocalNotifications)

Answer (score 1):

Have you set UserInfo while fire notification? In Sample code it is `nil` .Check i have set `userinfo = andInfo:@{@"a":@"ab"}`

```
[[MKLocalNotificationsScheduler sharedInstance] scheduleNotificationOn:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10]
                                                                  text:@"Hey there" 
                                                                action:@"View" 
                                                                 sound:nil 
                                                           launchImage:nil 
                                                               andInfo:@{@"a":@"ab"}];
```

and in Log i get

> Received: {fire date = Friday, September 4, 2015 at 12:25:44 PM India Standard Time, time zone = Asia/Kolkata (GMT+5:30) offset 19800, repeat interval = 0, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = (null), user info = {
>       a = ab;
>   }}

Comment: i know when the app is on the foreground didReceiveLocalNotification will call  , your code is fine , but my Question is different did you checked my sample code

Comment: Thanks but after implementing this notification is not working on foreground

Comment: @nivritgupta it is working in foreground. the log is while app is in foreground. maybe you've done some mistake. write `NSLog(@"Received: %@",[thisNotification description]);` in `didReceiveLocalNotification`

Comment: i know  your code is fine . but if you checking the demo code  .. the notification alert view  is working only when the app is on the background  ,  but when the app is on the foreground the UILocalNotification alert view is not working

Comment: @nivritgupta You have to add alert code. That library didnt add alert code. You have to add code by your self.that library will not do everything. We have to customize by our self

Comment: Yes i know we add alertview , badges , and sound by yourself , but if you checking this code https://github.com/MugunthKumar/LocalNotifications     Alertview is working when the app is on the background  mode , i already implementing UILocalNotification  in many apps but i did not understand why the  Notfication Alertview is not working when the appp is on the foreground ,

Comment: @nivritgupta First you should know while app is in background you can not handle local notification. It will show alert or banner as per ios app default setting not as per code. Its not in your hand while app is in background. First you should understand basics regarding ios that what we can handle and what we cannot. It will help you

Comment: if you check the demo code then you will see that  user set the Alertview using UILocalnotification displaying after 20 or 10 sec , the alertview is displaying properly when your app is on the background , my Question is simple why the Alertview is not display when the app in the foreground :-)

Comment: Can you even compile the demo code? It's iOS 4 compatible. We have iOS 9 now.

Comment: @Alistra  i already implementing the  registerUserNotificationSettings Methods and make this code compatible with ios 8 ,  In iOS 8.0 and later, your application must register for user notifications using -[UIApplication registerUserNotificationSettings:] before being able to schedule and present UILocalNotifications

Comment: @nivritgupta In Sample Code there is no code which shows Alertview. First you should know that when app is foreground you have to show alert using code. when app is in background iOS settings will handle. If you choose banner then it will show banner. looks like you choose Alert that why app is showing alert while app is in background. In Demo code they have just decrease Badge count. they didnt show AlertView. Please do some r&d regarding localnotification & iOS Basics.